# Which limits involve computing square roots, Such as $\sqrt{n^2+6} -n$

Tags: limits, radicals

Please help me to computing this square limit. And if possible give me some website where have same tasks. Thank you!
$\sqrt{n^2+6} -n$

Comment: I've tried to edit the question to what I thought you were asking, so please edit it yourself if it does not match your intentions.

Comment: ......what....?

Comment: $n$ tends to what?

Comment: Here's a website you can try: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30040?lq=1

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: You could probably find several similar questions on this site. You can have a look at the list of related questions or [frequent questions tagged limits+radicals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits+radicals?sort=frequent). Some reasonable queries in Approach0 like [this one](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E2%2B6%7D%20-n%24&p=1) or [this one](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D(%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E2%2B6%7D%20-n)%24&p=1) lead to a few similar posts, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual trick is to realize that

$$\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}$$

can be slightly simplified by multiplying by 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}}
$$
In your case, $a = n^2 + 6$ and $b = n^2$. Give it a try and see how it simplifies.

It relies on the idea that $(x + y) (x - y) = x^2 - y^2$, so if $x$ is written as a square-root, the right hand side does NOT have that square root.

Answer (score 1):

Take a few terms of the binomial expansion:

$$\sqrt{n^2+6}=n+\frac3n+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

Thus,

$$\sqrt{n^2+6}-n=\frac3n+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$